# Is /var/spool automatically removed/cleaned

Tags: linux, tmp

My app is keeping files in `/var/spool/myapp` and that works fine.  If my app crashes, then it might leave files in that directory.

Over time, this can add up to a lot of files, so I wondered if the `/var/spool` directory contents are automatically deleted on reboot, or after a period of time (sort of like `/var/tmp`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s14.html), `/var/spool` is the directory for data which awaits further processing e.g. printer queues and other queued work. Each different spool has its own subdirectory. It is not cleaned periodically or on reboot; usually contents get deleted once they have been processed by the relevant service.

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* a temporary directory per se, it's not cleaned up automatically by default by any distro that I'm aware of.

You could use `tmpwatch` to do that or write your own routine using `crontab`.